# Firefox ругается на jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, firefox

Постоянно в консоли:

```
ReferenceError: jQuery is not defined
})(jQuery);

ReferenceError: $ is not defined
$(document).ready(function(){
```

и подобное.
В хроме и опере все нормально.
Библиотеку подключаю самой первой.
Почему так, что делать?

Comment: Можно ссылку на сайт?

Comment: http://tankist10.hosting-test.org.ua/

Comment: А у Вас там никаой Noscript не хулиганит?

Comment: браузер чистый, стоит только firebug

Answer (score 1):

Возможно Вы пытаетесь использовать jQuery еще до того, как он загружен (по иерархии кода)